# How is Security dealt with in Spring XD?

Tags: security, spring-xd

Just having a quick look at Spring XD, I've had a look at the documentation and had a few questions regarding security.

First off, I notice that the default transport for comms is Redis which prefers to live within a trusted network segment.  In our environment that is a non starter by both policy and practical network & systems topology terms so we'd need to swap in something else which we could do proper authentication on.  Has anyone within the dev team got any practical experience with a transport that is not redis and that has supported authentication?

Secondly, how else is authentication and authroization done within the application. If I can reach the Admin I can deploy anything I like?  I suppose I'm missing the big section on how to secure the infrastructure and inter tier communications and information flows.

I entirely appreciate this is M1 and with the pedigree of spring security (something we use alot) I'm sure this is all waiting in the wings for when you have a moment to catch your breath.  For the moment we'll likely watch and wait with interest.

Kind Regards,
Max

Answer (score 2):

As you say; early days yet... but we anticipate a variety of transports - probably RabbitMQ is next; Spring Integration already has channels that can be secured with Spring Security so I would anticipate Spring Security support to be high on the list both from an admin and stream perspective; XD will also need the ability to propagate Spring Security contexts across the transport between modules, etc, etc...

Good questions; more good stuff coming...